# Unable to accept float input on a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing a review application and when submitting the review the reviewer has to include the coordinates of the restaurant which will then populate a map.

But I am struggling on how to accept the float input, the string input works fine. I have highlighted in the code below where I am having difficulty, I tried to use "**Float.valueOf**" however that caused my application to crash.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_note, container, false);
    mAttractionName = view.findViewById(R.id.Submit_attractionName);
    mReview = view.findViewById(R.id.Submit_review);

    mAttractionAddress = 
    view.findViewById(R.id.Submit_attraction_Address);
    mCuisine = view.findViewById(R.id.Submit_Cuisine);
    mLat = view.findViewById(R.id.Submit_latitude);
    mLong = view.findViewById(R.id.Submit_longitude);
    mCreate = view.findViewById(R.id.create);
    mCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    mCreate.setOnClickListener(this);

    getDialog().setTitle("New Attraction");

    return view;
   }

    @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.create:{

            // insert the new note

            String attractionName = mAttractionName.getText().toString();
            String review = mReview.getText().toString();
            String attractionAddress = enter code 
            heremAttractionAddress.getText().toString();
            String cuisine = mCuisine.getText().toString();
            Float latitude = mLat.getText().toString(); (ISSUES HERE)
            Float longitude = mLong.getText().toString();



            if(!attractionName.equals("")){
                mSUBMITACTIVITY.createNewNote(attractionName, re`enter 
        code here`view, cuisine, attractionAddress, latitude, longitude);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter an Attraction", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }

        case R.id.cancel:{
            getDialog().dismiss();
            break;
          }
       }
   }
```

XML of the EditText

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_wrapper4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/Submit_latitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/note_latitude"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_wrapper5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/Submit_longitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/note_longitude"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String latitude = mLat.getText().toString();
float f = Float.parseFloat(latitude);
```

You have to take the input in string and then convert it.